# Spring - Exceptions do not log to a file

Tags: spring, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm currently using SLF4J API for logging.

Whenever an exception is thrown during runtime, the full error stack trace does not log to file, it is only printed to the console. I'm using eclipse.

Here is my code for logback.xml *(currently located in classes folder under WEB-INF)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>

<configuration>
    <!-- Specify here the path of the folder you want to save your logs -->
    <property name="LOGFILE_PATH" value="C:/Logs" />

    <!-- All logging will be redirected/ printed to console. -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %rEx %msg%n </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send log to file -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOGFILE_PATH}/spring-mybatis-log.log</File>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %rEx %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGFILE_PATH}/spring-mybatis-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.txt
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

1. Is there something missing/wrong with the above file??
2. Is it possible to log (to a file) all the text that will be printed to console?
3. How does spring(or the project itself) read the logback.xml file? What if I rename it and place it in another folder?
4. How to create one **root** containing all the **levels** (INFO, DEBUG, ERROR, WARN, etc..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Nothing looks obviously wrong to me in the file you've posted, although I didn't try actually running it.
2. Just the way you did it is fine, with two appenders, one that goes to the file and the other to go to the console.
3. Logback by default looks in the classpath for the logback.xml file. Refer to the [configuration page of the manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration) for the details. The way it gets there depends on your build system. When using Maven, I'd suggest putting it in `src/main/resources`. But if it ends up in `WEB-INF/classes` when deployed in your web app, that should work. If no matter what you put in your logback.xml file you are only getting console output (try adding a syntax error or renaming the file to test), that's what I'd look at first, to ensure that Logback is picking up the file right. It will default to showing everything just on the console if it can't find the file, though I think it shows a warning at the beginning that it's doing so. If it is picking up the file, you can try putting [`debug="true"`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData) in the `<configuration>` element, to see if there's an error that it's picking up that's causing it to not use the appender the way you're expecting.
4. Specifying the "DEBUG" level of logging, as you've done, will also get all higher levels as well.

If the issue is that logging from Spring isn't going where you want, while *your* application's logging is working fine, you may need to redirect Spring (which uses Apache Commons Logging) to use SLF4J instead. To do that, remove the commons-logging dependency and add the jcl-over-slf4j library. This will emulate the commons-logging calls and have them point to SLF4J instead. See the "Using SLF4J" section of [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks OK, but you can try use your root level **INFO** instead **DEBUG** and if you have frameworks like spring, hibernate etc. Logback allow you uses another levels to them something like:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc" level="INFO" />
```